# Open .pdf file using path directory stored in string variable

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im having trouble with the "Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)" (android kotlin), i've searched the whole internet and can't find a updated solution to this.

Seens kinda simple, in my code I have this line of code:

```
private fun openFilePicker() {
        filePickerLauncher.launch("*/*")
    }
```

```
private val filePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            val filePath = uri.path
            if (filePath != null) {
                pdfPath = filePath
            }
        }
    }
```

So, after picking any file, my variable "pdfPath" have a string that points to the path of the file I just selected, like:

`pdfPath = /document/primary:ExampleFolder/Example.pdf`

Is there any way to open this file having the path?

Obs: The file is located internally in the cellphone. It could be anywere on the phone, I just need a way to open a specific file based on the value on "pdfPath"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, after picking any file

Your code is not tied to files.

> my variable "pdfPath" have a string to point to the path of the file I just selected, like:

No, it does not. It contains an arbitrary series of characters. There is no requirement that `path` of a `Uri` be a filesystem path. And, notably, yours is not a filesystem path.

> Is there any way to open this file having the path?

Get rid of `path`. Use the `Uri`, passing that into your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, such as:

```kotlin
        if (uri != null) {
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri))
        }
```

> The file is located internally in the cellphone

Not necessarily. It could be anywhere. `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent` is not limited to the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But your solution opens the pdf file as I pick it, I need to open the file without the picking part, like, running a line of code that will open the "exemple.pdf", any clue?

Comment: @JonathandaCosta: You have no rights to `exemple.pdf`. If your objective is to pick the content at one point and open it later, switch to `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`, [take persistable permissions to the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), and save the full `Uri`.

Comment: I just need a way to show with any external app (like acrobat, or office365) a pdf file on command, so there's no way to do that? kinda bummer.

Comment: @JonathandaCosta: You have no rights to arbitrary PDF content. except via user interaction (e.g., `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`). You are welcome to request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, at which point you *do* have rights to arbitrary PDF content, using simple filesystem paths. You could then use `FileProvider` to extend those rights to other apps. However, you are unlikely to be able to convince Google (and perhaps others) to allow you to distribute the app.

Comment: oh no, its not for public use, its for internal use only, any tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: @JonathandaCosta: "its not for public use, its for internal use only" -- how are you distributing it to the internal users? If it via the Play Store, I do not know that Google will let you distribute it, even if it is internal-only. FWIW, I cover `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in [this section](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-scoped-007.html) of [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-scoped-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R).

Comment: Not via play store, through the usb port directly (APK), thanks for all the help.